# How to make it to where the bot in discord dms a person by their ID and with the message given

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm wondering how you can do this I'm stuck on it where a random user DMS the bot with cv?buy [code] then the bot takes the message from the bot and users dm and sends the users message to another user using their ID with the users sent message from their's and the bots dms

[image]

Comment: You should show an example/snippet of your code where you tried working on this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're actually trying to do. Are you just wanting to DM a user with a given ID?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, and confirm if I'm right. You want: User1 to DM bot1. Then bot1 will DM bot2 AND user2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your wanted result (im using my ID so he messages me back):

[image: bot gif]

```
client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith("cv?buy") == true) {
    let msg = message.content;
    let arr = msg.split(" "); // make it into an array
    let user = client.users.cache.get(arr[1]); // array's position 1 is the ID
    let code = ""; // this will be the message
    for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) { // go from position 2 to the end of array
      code += `${arr[i]} `; // add those words to the message
    }
    user.send(code); // send the message to the user whose ID you typed
  }

});
```

Of course the syntax will be: `cv?buy [user.id] [message]`